# How do hashCode() and identityHashCode() work at the back end?

Tags: java, object, hashcode

How do [`Object.hashCode()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) and [`System.identityHashCode()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode(java.lang.Object)) work at the back end? Does `identityHashCode()` return the reference of the object? Does `hashCode()` depend on the content or address of the object?

What is the difference between `hashCode()` and `identityHashCode()`?

Comment: [How does the JVM ensure that System.identityHashCode() will never change?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063068/how-does-the-jvm-ensure-that-system-identityhashcode-will-never-change) will help in clearing some ambiguousness.

Answer (score 45):

> How do Object.hashCode() and System.identityHashCode() work at the back end?

Assuming that it hasn't been overridden, the `Object.hashCode()` method simply calls `System.identityHashCode(this)`.

The exact behavior of `System.identityHashCode(Object)` depends on the JVM implementation. (The actual implementation on recent Hotspot JVMs is rather clever, but I digress.)

> Does `identityHashCode()` return the reference of the object?

No. It returns an `int`, and an `int` cannot hold a reference.

That integer returned by `identityHashCode` may be related to the (a) machine address for the object, or it may not be<sup>1</sup>.  The value returned by `identityHashCode()` *is guaranteed not to change* for the lifetime of the object. This means that if the GC relocates an object (after an `identityHashCode()` call) then it cannot use the new object address as the identity hashcode.

> Does hashCode() depend on the `?` of the object `? ==` operator how to work in back end.

This doesn't make sense. There is no `? ==` or `?==` operator in Java.

> What is the difference between hashCode() and identityHashCode()?

This is partly explained above. Other differences include:

- The `hashCode()` method is a non-`final` instance method, and should be overridden in any class where the `equals(Object)` is overridden. By contrast, `identityHashCode(Object)` is a `static` method and therefore cannot be overridden.
- The `identityHashCode(Object)` method gives you a identifier for an object which can (in theory) be used for other things than hashing and hash tables. (Unfortunately, it is not a *unique* identifier, but it *is* guaranteed to never change for the lifetime of the object.)

---

<sup>1 - For current generation JVMs, it is not related to the memory address at all. See @bestsss's answer.</sup>

Answer (score 28):

`identityHashCode()` works like that (*and as of now it has nothing do to with the address, especially since the addresses are 64bits long, ok aligned, so 61*):

Checks if there is already generated one, if so returns it. You can assume there is a place in the object header for that `int`;

**Otherwise:** Generates a random number ([Marsaglia shift-xor](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/runtime/synchronizer.cpp#l560) algorithm). Every native thread has its own seed, so no shared info.
CAS the `identityHashCode` field in the object header to update w/ the newly generated number. If CAS succeeds, returns the value. If not, the field already contains a generated `identityHashCode`.

You can see the rest of the replies about overriding hashcode.

**Bottom line:**
If the JavaDoc still states anything about addresses and `identityHashCode`, someone needs to update it.

Comment: There are 5 alternatives of hash code calculation in the code. Looking at [this](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/runtime/globals.hpp#l1148) one can see that option 5, Marsaglia shift-xor, is really currently used. Hashcode generation has been elaborated more in [this blog post](https://srvaroa.github.io/jvm/java/openjdk/biased-locking/2017/01/30/hashCode.html)

Answer (score 13):

This is pretty much implementation specific.  The only guarantee you get is

> As much as is reasonably practical, the `hashCode` method defined by class `Object` does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the Java<sup>TM</sup> programming language.)

(From the Java 1.6 JavaDoc)

In theory, this means that the values could be determined arbitrarily and could even be zero for every object.  In practice, it's probably something derived from the address of the object.  Of course, you have to be careful about this.  The JVM can relocate objects if it thinks it's a good idea during a garbage collection, so it's not going to be "just" the memory address.  It could be drawn from a global counter, or a hash of the original object's location, or from a random number generator, etc.

Comment: You're right, I must have mixed something up. I got stuck in the documentation to back my hypotesis -- but failed. ;-) deleted my answer and upvoted yours!

Comment: what is the difference between hashCode() and identityHashCode()?

Comment: @Himanshu- `Object.hashCode()` is the default implementation of `hashCode()` and is often overridden by derived classes to conform to the rules for `equals()`/`hashCode()`.  `System.identityHashCode()` provides a way to get the value that `Object.hashCode()` would return for that object even if it contains an override for this method.  This allows you to make containers that work with identity semantics, since `==` and `System.identityHashCode()` treat each object uniquely.

Comment: The idea that hashCode uses the memory address is a historical artefact http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36236615/does-object-tostring-or-object-hashcode-ever-give-the-memory-address-of-the-obje

Answer (score 9):

Lots of answers given above, just need to add some points.

When we say `obj.hashCode()` the content of the obj is considered, on the other hand 
in `System.identityHashCode(obj)` the content are not taken in consideration, thus `identityHashCode` for two different `String`, `int`(with same value) will be the different but `Hashcode` will be the same.

In case of `String` to get `identityHashCode` string pool plays important role, example

```
    Object s1 = "abcd";
    Object s2 = new String("abcd");
    Object s3 = "abcd";
    System.out.println("identityHashCode : " + System.identityHashCode(s1) + " HashCode : " + s1.hashCode());
    System.out.println("identityHashCode : " + System.identityHashCode(s2) + " HashCode : " + s2.hashCode());
    System.out.println("identityHashCode : " + System.identityHashCode(s3) + " HashCode : " + s3.hashCode());

    //output:
    identityHashCode : 2018699554 HashCode : 2987074
    identityHashCode : 1311053135 HashCode : 2987074
    identityHashCode : 2018699554 HashCode : 2987074
```

here `s1` and `s3` pointing same ref therefore `identityHashCode` for `s1 and s3` is always same and `s2` will be different.

Same for `int` also, `IntegerCache` plays the important role to get the `identityHashCode`

```
    Object s1 = 5;
    Object s2 = new Integer(5);
    Object s3 = 5;
    System.out.println("identityHashCode : " + System.identityHashCode(s1) + " HashCode : " + s1.hashCode());
    System.out.println("identityHashCode : " + System.identityHashCode(s2) + " HashCode : " + s2.hashCode());
    System.out.println("identityHashCode : " + System.identityHashCode(s3) + " HashCode : " + s3.hashCode());

    //Output
    identityHashCode : 2018699554 HashCode : 5
    identityHashCode : 1311053135 HashCode : 5
    identityHashCode : 2018699554 HashCode : 5
```

Answer (score 5):

> #### identityHashCode
>
> public static int identityHashCode(Object x)
>
> *Returns the same hash code for the given object as would be returned by the default method hashCode()*, whether or not the given object's class overrides hashCode(). The hash code for the null reference is zero.

See [[Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode(java.lang.Object))]

So if someone has overridden `hashCode()` method in its class but still want the default `hashCode()` value which would have been returned by *Object* `hashCode()` then use `System.identityHashCode()`

So, `hashCode()` internally calls `System.identityHashCode()` ***as long as you are not overriding it in you class, if you override hashCode() it will call your implementation.***

Answer (score 0):

**A very well understanding you will get from below code:**

identityHashCode() will give you the memory address (a number) of String literal in String pool whereas hashcode() method of Object class will give you the same hash value for all the objects which are same (having same string literal)

```
    String a = new String("abc"); // "abc" will not be added to String constant pool.

    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(a)); // 460141958

    String b = a.intern();// add s to String constant pool
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(b)); // 1163157884

    String c = "abc"; // OR String c = b;
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(c)); // 1163157884

    String d = new String("abc"); // OR String d = new String(c)
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(d)); // 1956725890

    String e = new String(new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c'});
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(e)); // 356573597
    System.out.println(e.intern() == b); //true

    System.out.println();
    String str2 = "hello";
    String str1 = new String("hello");
    String str3 = str1.intern();
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(str2)); // 1735600054
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(str1)); // 21685669
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(str3)); // 1735600054
    System.out.println(str2 == str3); // true
    System.out.println(str3 == str1); // false

    String str4 = new String(new char[]{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'}); //// "hello" will not be added to String constant pool.
    System.out.println(str4.intern() == str2); //true
```

Comment: The code provided is very explanatory, but the introductory explanation is not entirely correct. `identityHashCode` does not return a memory address. It returns the result of hashCode() as if it wasn't overridden from Object's default implementation.