# how to implement HashCode() for a node containing only reference to next node?

Tags: java, reference, hashcode

```
public class Node {
    private Node nextNode;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        //How to implement this?
        //Because you just have a attribute which is a reference.
        //I think the attribute is almost useless, because if you use the HashCode of the attribute, you will finally fall into a useless loop.
        //Thus, I think you should find a way to represent the HashCode of reference (instance) itself.
    }
}
```

From the comment in the code, my question is actually how to uniquely identify reference itself, like address in C.

Comment: My guess is that this is supposed to be a base class.  If so, don't bother implementing it because there's no use for a node that only points to the next node, is there?  You'll never use it without extending it, I'm guessing.  Perhaps make the class abstract to enforce this?

Comment: If you did want to override hashcode, the proper declaration is `public int hashCode() {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `Node`'s hash-code to represent its *own* reference — that is, if you're not overriding `equals(Object)` — then you don't need to override `hashCode()` at all.

If you want the `Node`'s hash-code to represent the reference of its `nextNode` — that is, if your `equals(Object)` looks something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object that)
{
    return ((that instanceof Node) && (nextNode == ((Node) that).nextNode));
}
```

— then you can use [the JDK's `System.identityHashCode(Object)` utility method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    return System.identityHashCode(nextNode);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Accepted because mention of 1."identityHashCode". Difference between HashCode and indentityHashCode can be found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930781/how-do-hashcode-and-identityhashcode-work-at-the-back-end 2.You are correct The default implementation of Sun's SDK hashCode() method, is a return value 
 * that will be the memory address of the object.

Answer (score 9):

There is nothing you need to do here, the `Node` already has the default implementation which returns a hash code based on the memory location it resides at.

Comment: Nowadays this is not the case anymore and `hashCode()` isn't related to actual in-memory address. See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8199394