# How every object are different from one another

Tags: java, hashcode

I have read articles about object identity in object oriented context.Which says "Every object you create has its own unique identity". But I got confused by below code.

```
     String str="Hello";
     String str1="Hello";
     System.out.println(str.hashCode()); //69609650
     System.out.println(str1.hashCode()); //69609650
     System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(str));//19313225
     System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(str1));//19313225
```

hash code and identityhashcode for both str and str1 are same. **Please correct me if I understood wrong.**

Also what is difference between hashcode() and system.identityhashcode()

Comment: Note that the hash code is not always unique for different objects; the hash code is not a unique identifier for objects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're seeing is because you're using `String`, which has a very special (and *nearly* unique) behavior: Your two strings are actually one `String` object, because string literals are automatically [`intern`'d](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29). The JDK and JVM work together to put string literals into a pool of `String` instances which are reused, rather than creating separate `String` instances for the same sequence of characters.

Try your experiment with `new Object()` instead:

```
 Object a = new Object();
 Object b = new Object();
 System.out.println(a.hashCode());
 System.out.println(b.hashCode());
 System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(a));
 System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(b));
```

---

> Also what is difference between hashcode() and system.identityhashcode()

The `hashCode` function can be overridden by a class to return something appropriate for that class. [`System.identityHashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode%28java.lang.Object%29) returns the same `hashCode` that [`Object#hashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) *would* have returned if the subclass hadn't overridden it.

So for `Object`, you'd get the same return value from each of them. But for any class that overrides `hashCode` to return something more appropriate for that class (which includes `String`), you'd get different values.

Comment: Adding to @TJ's answer, even `new String("Hello");` would show the difference in `identityHashCode`!

Comment: @R.J: True, but I didn't want to introduce even more confusion. :-)

Comment: +1 I would also add that `new String()` means `create new object on heap/return new object` and `String a="text"` means `use existing object from heap/string pool.`

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you declare

```
String s2 = new String("Hello")
```

,

```
System.identityHashCode(s2);
```

will return different hashcode. This is because when declaration is like

```
String s = "something"
```

, jvm checks string pool to find out if there is identical literal. When declaration is like

```
String s = new String("something");
```

jvm always creates a new object.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answer, you can read a discussion around your second question here: [How do hashCode() and identityHashCode() work at the back end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930781/how-do-hashcode-and-identityhashcode-work-at-the-back-end)

Comment: You could have posted this as an comment to @TJ's answer instead of mentioning it here and giving just another link!

Answer (score 0):

As said in the documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode(java.lang.Object)), identityHashCode gives the same HashCode, wether or not the hashCode method was overriden.

Comment: 1. This is a comment, not an answer to the question. The question is about why the OP sees the same value when he thought he had two separate objects. 2. It's a duplicate of the same comment made by Sajan several minutes prior.

Comment: Well, the OP had 2 questions in his post. As the first one was already answered, I answered the second one.

Comment: So, then, this was just a duplicate of Sajan's answer. (But he's deleted his answer now.)

Answer (score 0):

Both your objects are interned string constants. The JVM ensures the are the same objects.

The difference between hashCode and identityHashCode is hashCode is a hash of the *balue* of the string object, whereas the identityHashCode is a hash of the ibject's internal identifier.

Answer (score 0):

> You are not using String objects, you are using String literals..
>   There is a very big difference between them.  In your case, str and
>   str1 both are pointing to the same "Hello" object in String pool.  Try
>   doing something like this :

```
StringBuilder sb1= new StringBuilder("Hello");
StringBuilder sb2= new StringBuilder("Hello");
System.out.println(sb1.hashCode()); 
System.out.println(sb2.hashCode()); 
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(sb1));
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(sb2));
```

> output : 7214088 15020296 7214088 15020296
>
> As StringBuilder creates new objects, you can see that the hashCodefor
>   sb1 and sb2 are different. Which means they are not pointing to the
>   same object. But str1 and str2 are pointing to the same String object.
>   Read somthing about String Pools and permgen space for further
>   information.