# Address of String object in JAVA

Tags: java

I have a question about address of object in JAVA.

the following is my code.

```
public class StringCompare {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "apple";
        String s2 = "apple";
        String s3 = new String("apple");

        boolean b1 = (s1 == s2);
        boolean b2 = (s1 == s3);
        boolean b3 = s1.equals(s2);

        System.out.println(b1); // true
        System.out.println(b2); // false
        System.out.println(b3); // true

        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("Address of s1 = " + Integer.toHexString(s1.hashCode()));    // 58b835a 
        System.out.println("Address of s2 = " + Integer.toHexString(s2.hashCode()));    // 58b835a
        System.out.println("Address of s3 = " + Integer.toHexString(s3.hashCode()));    // 58b835a
    }
}
```

I think address of object(s1 and s2) is same. 
I think Address of object(s3) is not equal to s1, s2.

but..
result is address of object(s1, s2, s3) is same.

[image]

I don't know why s1, s2, s3 address is same..

Please give me some advice. 
Thanks.

Comment: `hashcode()` is **not** the address of an object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do hashCode() and identityHashCode() work at the back end?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930781/how-do-hashcode-and-identityhashcode-work-at-the-back-end)

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation for [`Object.hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()):

> If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

Since `String` overrides `equals()`, it also overrides `hashCode()` in order to fulfill this contract. This means that two distinct object which are `equals()` will still have the same hashcode. Note that this means that the hashcode is **not** the address of the object. (Although, the default implementation in `Object.hashCode()` returns a unique identifier of the object itself, which is somewhat similar to its address. Note that this satisfies the `equals()` contract because the default implementation returns true only when comparing two references to the same object.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the address of a `String`. The [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) of `Object` returns something like an address, but `String` overrides [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29). Finally, you can test for reference equality with `==` but (as you seem to know), you use `.equals()` for equality testing.

Answer (score 0):

`.hashcode()` does not return an address, it returns a hash value which every class in Java implicitly provides. For more info you can read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode())