# Faster hashCode() alternative?

Tags: java

Is there any way to make hashCode() faster? Of course I understand that this will probably result in more collisions, but I am OK with this trade off.

Does java have a way to "get the memory address of an Object, like C++ does?

**edit:** To be clear: I understand that hashCode() is fast. My goal is to make a hash function that is as fast as some C++ hash functions.

The type of item I will be hashing is not known.

Comment: See also: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/49550 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/4933258/954442

Comment: Depending on your use-case you could also pre-calculate or cache your hashCode values so that if there's lots of hashing the cost is minimised.

Comment: @Andrew Regan: Thanks, cache is a great idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to make hashCode() faster?

Yes, many ways but it depends on what you are hashing.

Note: the built in Object.hashCode() takes around 40 ns.

> Does java have a way to "get the memory address of an Object, like C++ does?

Yes, you can use Unsafe to do this, however this is a bad idea as the address of an object can change at any time making it useless as a hash.

---

This program triggers the re-calcuation of Object.hashCode().

**Note: this is very hacky and might not work on all JVM or future JVMs. It is for education purposes only.**

```
public class HashCodePerf {
    static int keep;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object o = new Object();
        int runs = 20_000_000;
        for (int t = 0; t < 5; t++) {
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
                UNSAFE.putInt(o, 1L, 0); // reset the memory which stores the hashCode
                keep = o.hashCode(); // compute a new hashCode
            }
            long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
            System.out.printf("Object.hashCode takes %,d ns on average%n", time / runs);
        }
    }

    static final Unsafe UNSAFE;

    static {
        try {
            Field theUnsafe = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
            theUnsafe.setAccessible(true);
            UNSAFE = (Unsafe) theUnsafe.get(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

prints on my Ultra-book

```
Object.hashCode takes 79 ns on average
Object.hashCode takes 43 ns on average
Object.hashCode takes 48 ns on average
Object.hashCode takes 43 ns on average
Object.hashCode takes 42 ns on average
```

---

Creating a very simple hash which is adding to counter.

```
static int keep, keep2;
static int counter;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object o = new Object();
    Object o2 = new Object();
    int runs = 100_000_000;
    for (int t = 0; t < 5; t++) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < runs; i+=2) {
            UNSAFE.putOrderedInt(o, 1L, (counter += 0x5bc80bad) & 0x7FFFFFFF);
            UNSAFE.putOrderedInt(o2, 1L, (counter += 0x5bc80bad) & 0x7FFFFFFF);
            keep = o.hashCode(); // reload the hashCode
            keep2 = o2.hashCode(); // reload the hashCode
        }
        long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.printf("Object.hashCode takes %,d ns on average%n", time / runs);
    }
}
```

prints

```
Object.hashCode takes 5 ns on average
Object.hashCode takes 8 ns on average
Object.hashCode takes 5 ns on average
Object.hashCode takes 4 ns on average
Object.hashCode takes 4 ns on average
```

Note: normally the address of an object changes, but it's hashCode doesn't. In this case we have the objects with changing hashCode but with the same address.

Comment: Can you please provide more information on how I can write my own hashCode?

Comment: Object.hashCode() is slower compared to some C++ hash functions. Any way to make it as fast as C++?

Comment: @MATH000 You override hashCode() you can make it as fast as C++ but how you do this depends on the data you are hashing. There is no one size fits all approach.

Comment: Is Hash Code calculated automatically when a object is created regardless if I call the function or not?

Comment: @MATH000 it is calculated the first time it is called i.e. lazily.  See my example above where I cut the time to `4 ns` on average.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to make hashCode() faster? Of course I understand that this will probably result in more collisions, but I am OK with this trade off.

The best answer for this particular question is:

```
public int hashCode() {
     return 0;
}
```

It is correct for any `Object`, it is as fast as it gets, and it will provide you with tons of collisions, which you are OK with.

Comment: My goal is find a balance between the collisions and the speed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something similar to the object's address, you can use:

```
System.identityHashCode(obj);
```

If the hascode method is called many times, you can also cache/pre-calculate the result (assuming the object is immutable or at least that its hashcode does not change after construction).

```
class CashHashcode {
  private final int hash;
  CacheHashcode(...) {
    hash = computeHashFromArgs(...);
  }
  public int hashCode() { return hash; }
}
```

Comment: [`IdentityHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) ...?