# When does the jvm assign hashcode value in the object header

Tags: java, jvm

I have learned that the java **object header** contains the information such as *hashcode、gc year、biased lock* and so on. Then a puzzle come to me and in order express my question explicitly. I give an example.
Here is the code:

```
public class Demo{
    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        System.out.println("the hashCode method was called");
        return super.hashCode();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Demo demo = new Demo();
        System.out.println("after generate an object");
        //
        Set<Demo> set = new HashSet<Demo>();
        set.add(demo);
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
after generate an object
the hashCode method was called
```

I guess when we new an object the *jvm* will set **hashcode** in object header. But if this in order to generate hashCode it should be invoke *hashCode method* of this object.
**However** according to the output which seemed it havent invoke *hashCode method* when new an object. And add value into hashSet the *hashCode method* is invoked, this as was expected.

So my question is that: When does the jvm  assign hashcode value in the object header? It happened in the phase when new an object?

- If Yes. Why it havent invoke *hashcode method*, and without this how to calculate **hashcode** of this object.
- If No. Uhhh... It make no sense that update **hashcode** in *object header* every invoke *invoke hashCode method*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- JVM does not need to call `hashCode` method to initialize object's identity hashCode. It works the other way round: `Object.hashCode` and `System.identityHashCode` call JVM to compute or to extract previously computed identity hashCode.
- It is not specified how JVM generates and stores identity hashCode. Different JVM implementations may do it differently.
- *HotSpot JVM* computes identity hashCode on the first call to `Object.hashCode` or `System.identityHashCode` and stores it in the object header. The subsequent calls simply extract the previously computed value from the header.

Comment: Isn't identity hash code computed and saved in object header during object creation?

Comment: @Sher10ck No. This would significantly decrease performance of object allocation.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are confusing hashcode and identity-hashcode.

An object's hashcode will not be stored in the object header but is computed by calling the hashcode method as needed. In your example hashcode is called because you are adding your object to a `HashSet`.

The identity hashcode is computed by the JVM at object creation and serves - amongst others - as fallback for an object's hashcode value. That is `Object.hashcode()` will return the identity hashcode of your object. This value will **not** change during the lifetime of your object.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930781/how-do-hashcode-and-identityhashcode-work-at-the-back-end) for further details.