# Two references for the same singletonPattern instance

Tags: java, singleton

I was learning about the Singleton design pattern through a tutorial. Basically from what I understand it ensures that only one instance of a class is ever created, and any interaction with that class is done through that one instance in the heap. with that said, in the SingletonPatternDemo.java I wrote:

```
SingleObject object1 = SingleObject.getInstance();

SingleObject object2 = SingleObject.getInstance();
```

from my understanding, both object1 and object2 reference the same object, thus they should point to the same location in memory.

However when I write:

```
System.out.println("object1 HashCode: " + System.identityHashCode(System.identityHashCode(object1)));

System.out.println("object2 HashCode: " + System.identityHashCode(System.identityHashCode(object2)));
```

after I run it I get:

```
object1 HashCode: 865113938
object2 HashCode: 1442407170
```

since these two objects reference the same instance shouldn't they return the same hashcode? or   am I missing something?

[image: Singleton class]

[image: Demo class]

Comment: you're printing hash code of temp variable with hashcode

Comment: Why call System.identityHashCode() twice?

Comment: The traditional way to check if you have references to the same thing is to ask `object1 == object2` ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do hashCode() and identityHashCode() work at the back end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930781/how-do-hashcode-and-identityhashcode-work-at-the-back-end)

Comment: @moilejter this is just the way I saw was being done in a tutorial

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't post the code as an image. Use `System.identityHashCode(object1)` and `System.identityHashCode(object2)` to get the hash code of the object. Or you may simply use `object1.hashCode()` and `object2.hashCode()`.

Comment: This could be a fine question if you would not be using images in it.

Answer (score 3):

`System.identityHashCode(System.identityHashCode(object1))`

The inner `System.identityHashCode(object1)` will return an `int` that is the hash code of `object1`.

The outer call takes an `Object` - the `int` is [boxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) to an `Integer`. As it's outside of the [cached range](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)), the `Integer` object is created. It is this `Integer` for which the hash code is displayed.

`System.identityHashCode(System.identityHashCode(object2))`

Here, the inner call will return an `int` - the same one as for `object1`. **But**, as above, when you call `System.identityHashCode` the `int` is boxed to an `Integer` - a different instance to the above.

---

By way of illustration:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String hello = "Hello World";
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(hello));
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(hello));

    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(System.identityHashCode(hello)));
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(System.identityHashCode(hello)));
}
```

Output:

> //first two are the same
>   899644639
>   899644639
>   //second two differ
>   530737374
>   1332668132

Comment: A terrible tutorial that suggests that code, but a nice answer!

Comment: Thanks @GhostCat! I suspect it's a copy-pasta issue; although there are some very ... interesting tutorials out there.

Comment: Maybe maybe this answer will save the day for others running into the same tutorial...