# Experimenting with String creation

Tags: java, string, memory

I found an interesting case while testing with string creation and checking their hashcode.

In first case i created string using copy constructor:

```
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s1 = new String("myTestString");

        String s3 = s1.intern();

        System.out.println("S1: " + System.identityHashCode(s1) + "  S3:"
                + System.identityHashCode(s3));
    }


}
```

Output of above code is:

> S1: 816115710  S3:478684581

This is expected output as interned string picks the reference from String pool whereas s1 picks reference of new object. So their identity hash code is different.

Now if i create String using char array then i see some strange behavior:

```
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char[] c1 = { 'm', 'y', 'T', 'e', 's', 't', 'S', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n',
                'g' };

        String s5 = new String(c1);

        String s6 = s5.intern();

        System.out.println("S5: " + System.identityHashCode(s5) + "  S6:"
                + System.identityHashCode(s6));
    }

}
```

Output of above code is:

> S5: 816115710  S6:816115710

This is an unexpected output. How can interned String and new String object have same identityhashcode??

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063068/how-does-the-jvm-ensure-that-system-identityhashcode-will-never-change

Comment: @IgorS.: How is it linked to my question?

Comment: "Multiple objects can have the same identity hash code. That is the nature of hash codes."

Comment: @IgorS.: Yes they can have only in certain scenarios. In above scenario they should not have.

Comment: It should. To keep memory usage low - VM clearly use lazy loading, because you didn't do anything with strings it pointing to the same memory address. First case is probably different, because of characters encoding or/and string end character.

Comment: Although i disagree with your suggestion but even if we take that approach then s1 and s3 should also have same identity hash code, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, the `myTestString` literal is on the pool *before* you call `intern`, whereas in the second case it is not so your String `s5` is put in the pool directly.

If we go through your examples step by step, this is what happens:

- `String s1 = new String("myTestString");` => the use of a String literal creates a String `myTestString` in the pool (let's call it `s0`), and a new String `s1` is also created, which is not in the pool.
- `String s3 = s1.intern();` => checks if there is an equivalent String in the pool and finds `s0`. Now `s3` and `s0` refer to the same instance (i.e. `s3 == s0` is true, but `s1 != s0`).

In your second example:

- `String s5 = new String(c1);` creates a new String, which is not in the pool
- `String s6 = s5.intern();` checks if `myTestString` is in the pool but can't find it, so the call to `intern` creates a new String *reference* in the pool that refers to the same String as `s5`. So `s6 == s5` is true.

Finally you can run these two programs to confirm my explanation (the second one prints `true` three times):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = new String("myTestString");
    String s3 = s1.intern();
    System.out.println("myTestString" == s1);
    System.out.println(s3 == s1);
    System.out.println("myTestString" == s3);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = new String(new char[] {'m', 'y', 'T', 'e', 's', 't', 'S', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g'});
    String s3 = s1.intern();
    System.out.println("myTestString" == s3);
    System.out.println("myTestString" == s1);
    System.out.println(s3 == s1);
}
```

Comment: Why would s5 be put into pool directly? I am using new operator to create it.

Comment: It is put in the pool when you call intern because that specific string was not already in the pool. How you created the string is irrelevant in that case.

Comment: same should also apply to s1, s3 then. Why is that different?

Comment: @loki I have added more details. The difference is that in your first example there is a String literal which goes to the pool before your program runs.

Comment: +1 good point, didn't thought about explaining the "expected result" ;)

Comment: Well explained. But as per your explanation, when i call s5.intern(); then reference of s5 also changes. There is no such mention in javadoc, it only talks about return value of intern method. Do you any place where this is documented?

Comment: @loki No it does not change. The pool is simply a "list" of references, that refer to some strings. In the second case, the reference used is s5. In other words, calling `str.intern()` does something like: `if (there is a string s_p in the pool such that s_p.equals(str)) { return s_p; } else { return str; }`.

Comment: Perfect!! I can relate this to javadoc now. Thanks.